# Qorus nested select hash

Tags: sql

Is there any way I can have a select hash with a subquery inside the SELECT clause to be used on [SqlUtil::AbstractTable](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qore/modules/SqlUtil/html/class_sql_util_1_1_abstract_table.html) methods (like getRowIterator()).

I found something similar in [select_option_superquery](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qore/modules/SqlUtil/html/sql_operations.html#select_option_superquery) however the subquery used there is found in the FROM clause:

```
SELECT serviceid, service_methodid FROM (SELECT serviceid,service_methodid..)...
```

while I'm looking for something like:

```
    SELECT  t1.id, t1.order_id, 
     (SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM tbl1 t2 WHERE t1.order_id = t2.order_id) as count, 
     t1.other_cols,
     t3.other_cols 
    FROM tbl1 t1 left join tbl3 s on t1.id = t3.id
```

Desired outcome is to count in the result set the `order_id`

```
tbl1
id   order_id other_cols
1    ord1     ...
2    ord2     ...
3    ord1     ...
```

Result:

```
id   order_id   count   other_cols
1    ord1       2       ...
2    ord2       1       ...
3    ord1       2       ...
```

Comment: This is a really well asked first question! Good luck with it and welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can be solved using a window function: `count(*) over (partition by order_id) as cnt`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  Thanks for suggestion, will use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this exactly like what you wanted (with a subquery as a select column), but you can do this using the [superquery](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qore/modules/SqlUtil/html/sql_operations.html#select_option_superquery) option you mentioned and by using SQL window functions with SqlUtil with the [cop_over() function](https://qoretechnologies.com/manual/qorus/latest/qore/modules/SqlUtil/html/group__sql__cop__funcs.html#ga26ed96dc593836e3028d1bb17832c621)

The code could look as follows:

```
list cols = (
    "id",
    "order_id",
    cop_as(cop_over(cop_count("order_id"), "order_id"), "count"),
    # ... other columns to select here - this is in the inner query
    );

hash sh = (
    "columns": cols,
    "join": join_inner(t2, "t2", ("order_id": "order_id")) +
            join_inner(t3, "t3", ("id": "id")),
    "superquery": (
        "columns": (
            cop_distinct("id"), "order_id", "count"
            # note put columns needed here without table prefixes, this is for the outer query
        ),
    ),
    );
```

Subqueries are a little counterintuitive with SqlUtil, the subquery is specified with the top-level hash arguments, and the main query then (which selects from the subquery) is specified with the superquery hash key as in the example above.  Note that this will generate a query where there must be at least one row in `t2`.

If rows in `t2` are optional, use `join_left()` instead of `join_inner()`.

The following code would execute the query hash above and log the SQL generated and the results:

```
string sql;
list l = t1.selectRows(sh, \sql);
log(LL_INFO, "sql: %s", sql);
log(LL_INFO, "SQL results: %N", l);
```

I hope this helps!